# Обработка мыши WinAPI

Tags: winapi, c++

Собственно говоря я есть такая задача: 
отрисовать в окне некоторые фигуры, и заставить их мигать цветом при нажатии на них.
Как обрабатывать нажатие на конкретную фигуру?

Comment: Отслеживайте координаты мыши, при нажатии смотрите куда попали, перерисовывайте сцену в новых цветах.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно обрабатывать щелчок мыши в окне, например WM_LBUTTONDOWN, искать по координатам фигуру, в которую попали и перерисовывать её другим цветом. Потом не забыть нарисовать обратно правильным цветом.

Answer (score 4):

Если используется WinAPI, то можно представить фигуры в виде регионов (`CreateRectRgn`, `CreateEllipticRgn`, `CreatePolygonRgn`). Функция `PtInRegion` проверяет, входит ли точка в регион, а как найти координаты нужной точки, вам уже писали выше: обрабатывая сообщение `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`.