# Обработчик нажатия правой кнопки мыши

Tags: c++, c, winapi

На winApi пишу сапер.

Имеется массив кнопок, и нужно для каждой кнопки установить обработчик нажатия правой клавиши мыши над ней. Можно ли это реализовать? Каким образом?

Comment: А не будет ли вам в очередь сообщения для родительского окна приходить сообщение о нажатии ПКМ?

Comment: подобный вопрос был см.[ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/99141/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-winapi)

Answer (score 4):

Смотря, что за кнопка.

**Если кнопка - отдельное окно**, то обрабатывайте сообщения мыши в `WndProc`.
Создайте массив типа `HWND` и заполните его окнами(которые будете использовать, как кнопки), у которых один общий `WndProc`.Идентифицируйте, какая кнопка нажата с помощью цикла.Ниже код

```
HWND hwnds[100]={NULL};
hwnds[0]=CreateWindow(...);
hwnds[1]=CreateWindow(...);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp)

{

switch(message)
{

case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:

for(int i(0);i<100;i++)
if(hwnds[i]==NULL)
{
break;
}
else if(hwnd==hwnds[i])
{
...//Окно найдено
}
break;

}

}
```

**Если кнопка стандартная, Шиндоусовская**(но это тоже окно, насколько я помню), то через WM_COMMAND.Не пользуюсь, этим убожеством, поэтому код подсказать не могу. Но дам ссылку http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?62

**Бонус**

Рисуете прямоугольник, который будет Вашей кнопкой. При нажатии на окно(на котором Вы нарисовали прямоугольник) обрабатываете `WM_RBUTTONDOWN\UP`. Если коодрдинаты клика подходят, значит - кнопка нажата. Как это сделать:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp)
{
POINT cp;
GetCursorPos(&cp);//ну Вы поняли
switch(message)
{
case WM_PAINT:
...
Rectangle(hdc,10,10,50,30);
...
break;
case WM_RBUTTONUP:
{//не забудьте про скобки, если хотите объявить переменные внутри case`a

RECT r;
GetWindowRect(hwnd,&r);

int x=cp.x-r.left;//делаем координаты клика, относительно окна
int y=cp.y-r.top;//делаем координаты клика, относительно окна

if(x>10 && x<50 && y>10 && y<30)
{
...//тык
}

}
break;
}
}
```